# Getting error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I am getting this error continuously..I am using https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-5-add-inverse-data-flow but that's example is only working in jsfiddle when I paste that code in mvc's cshtml then it shows error at line `return (<tr><th`. is there any solution available?

Comment: Have you got [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/) installed?

Comment: @TomWalters no I have just installed react.js and react-dom.js..

Comment: Are u using webpack to bundle your files?

Answer (score 1):

`return (<tr><th` - contains JSX. 
Your environment doesn't know how to deal with JSX. In JSFiddle you probably have the Babel language selected. Babel transforms JSX to vanilla javascript (React.createElement(...)).

To see how JSX is transpilled you could use the online babel "try it out" editor:
http://babeljs.io/repl/. Just type a jsx element, and you will see the output.

You could look [here](http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/) to see how to integrate Babel into your set up.

Comment: I got it why it was showing error..I installed babel by ur given link..a small doubt how can I give reference of babel in my project? I installed it by `Install-Package React.Core`

Comment: Babel is suppose to run over your files and transpile them before they reach the actual browser's parsing. You can either transpile your files using the command line, and than serving those files to the browser. Or if you are using a build system such as webpack, you need to configure the build system to use it.